# gradle file error when i changed recyclerview version from 23.0.1 to 23.2.1

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "adhoc.mlm_app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.0.4"
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'//getting error

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 23.2.1, 23.0.1. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.1 and
>   com.android.support:design:23.0.1 )

Comment: So what? Make it all the same version. (see `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`).

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1' try this.. This is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 compile `'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'`
```

instead of

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`

Comment: Your welcome . If this help then vote it or mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

update gradle file with below code

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'//change here
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```